# Slider Plugin is not working in custom wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am new to wordpress , I am creating a custom wordpress theme where in index.php page I want to add some slider, for this I am using "Responsive WordPress Slider - Soliloquy Lite" plugin But after include its shortcode in page slider is not working . Slider images are coming below to each other. Below code is for slider which i am using in index.php of my custom wordpress theme.

```
 <div class="slider3">
 <?php if ( function_exists( 'soliloquy' ) ) { soliloquy( '16' ); } 
 if ( function_exists( 'soliloquy' ) ) { soliloquy( 'index-php-sliders','slug' ); } ?>
 </div>
```

[image: SLIDER IMAGE]
please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Sounds like a JavaScript issue or conflict. You should check your browser console to find out what's going on.

Comment: i have tried but able to solve this .could you please help to solve this issue .

Comment: I am using this slider plugin in a new wordpress theme , which has style.css , header.php , index.php.

Comment: use second shortcode <?php echo do_shortcode('[your slider shortcode]'); ?>

Comment: i have tried but its not working with "<?php echo do_shortcode('[your slider shortcode]'); ?>". Other slider plugins are working fine but this slider plugin is not working. any specific reason ?

Comment: Can you send your url.